# How to change minDate dynamically in xdsoft datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using this [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I tried below code but it's not working

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" id="txtDt">
<br>
<br>
<input type="text" id="txtDt2">
```

**JS :**

```
$('#txtDt').datetimepicker({
  format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
  formatTime: 'h:i A',            
  validateOnBlur: false,            
  defaultTime: '24:00',
  onSelectDate: function ($ct, $i) {
    var sDate = $i.val().substring(0, 10);
    $('#txtDt2').datetimepicker('setOptions', { minDate: sDate }); 
  }
});

$('#txtDt2').datetimepicker({
  format: 'd/m/Y h:i A',
  formatTime: 'h:i A',
  validateOnBlur: false,
  defaultTime: '23:59'
});
```

I get datetimepicker **`is not a function`** error in **`onSelectDate`** function. How to solve it ?

Comment: Have you added the scripts?

Comment: It works when i add a date manually to date formatting in the $('#txtDt2').datetimepicker function located under the $('#txtDt').datetimepicker

Comment: Upvote your question, you helped me a lot ! with : `$('#txtDt2').datetimepicker('setOptions', { minDate: sDate });`